# nodejs unirest post request - how to post complex rest / json body

Tags: javascript, node.js, unirest

Following is the unirest code I am using to post simple requests.

```
urClient.post(url)
    .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
    .end(
        function (response) {

        });
```

But now its required to send a complex json body with the POST call as shown below:

```
{
  "Key1": "Val1",
  "SectionArray1": [
    {
      "Section1.1": {
        "Key2": "Val2",
        "Key3": "Val3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "SectionPart2": {
        "Section2.1": {
            "Section2.2": {
                "Key4": "Val4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could this be done? What's the appropriate syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Request.send** method for that.Determines whether data mime-type is form or json.

```
var unirest = require('unirest');

unirest.post('http://example.com/helloworld')
.header('Accept', 'application/json')
.send({
  "Key1": "Val1",
  "SectionArray1": [
    {
      "Section1.1": {
        "Key2": "Val2",
        "Key3": "Val3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "SectionPart2": {
        "Section2.1": {
            "Section2.2": {
                "Key4": "Val4"
            }
        }
    }
})
.end(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

from the doc http://unirest.io/nodejs.html#request:

```
.send({
  foo: 'bar',
  hello: 3
})
```

so you can do:

```
urClient.post(url)
    .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
    .send(myComplexeObject) // You don't have to serialize your data (JSON.stringify)
    .end(
        function (response) {

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let objToSending = {
  "Key1": "Val1",
  "SectionArray1": [
    {
      "Section1.1": {
        "Key2": "Val2",
        "Key3": "Val3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "SectionPart2": {
        "Section2.1": {
            "Section2.2": {
                "Key4": "Val4"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

try add after second header this code (used your object):

```
.body(JSON.stringify(objToSending))
```

Comment: I think I will never understand that weird fashion that consists in stringifying JSON data. Everyone stringifies their JSON all the time, and then have re-parse it afterwards, and at this point I'm too afraid to ask why.

Comment: In this case, we will be sure that JSON data will have correct structure